# Several big O notations for the same function

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Let `f(n)= ( (n^2+2n)/n  +  1/1000*(n^(3/2)))*log(n)`

The time complexity for this function could be both `O(n²*log(n)) and O(n^(3/2)*log(n))`

How is this possible? I thought the dominating term here was `n² (*log(n))` and therefore it should be `O(n²*log(n))` only the big **O** notation and time complexity measures feels so ambiguous

Comment: there's no n^2 around, since (n^2+2n)/n = n+2

Comment: Okey, then: where is the n^2 coming from?

Comment: the complexity is O(O(n^(3/2)*log(n)) so this function IS O(1)

Comment: @jambono O(1)? How do you figure that? You can say f(n) = O(g(n)) where g(n) is **bigger** than or equal to f(n), not where g(n) is **smaller** than or equal to f(n), so saying it's O(n^99) is fine, but saying it's O(1) is not.

Comment: I was talking about the complexity of the function, the complexity of the function is O(1) even if f(n)=O(n^(3/2)*log(n))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Big O notation isn't that confusing. It defines an upper bound to the running time of an algorithm, hence, if `O(f(n))` is a valid upper bound, every other `O(g(n))` such that `g(n) > f(n)` definitively is valid, since if your code will run in less then `f(n)`, will for sure run in less than `g(n)`.

In your case, since `O(n^2 *log(n))` dominates `O(n^(3/2) log(n))`, it's a valid upper bound too, even if it's less strict. Furthermore, you could say that your algorithm is `O(n^3)`. The question is, which one of those Big O notation gives us more informations about the algorithm? The obvious answer is the lower one, and that's the reason why we usually indicate that.

To make things cler : let's say you can throw a ball up in the air 10m. Then, you can say that you can't throw higher than 10m, OR you could say you can't throw it higher than 15 meters. The fact that the first one is a stricter upper bound, doesn't make the second one a false statement.

Comment: Okey, so O(n^x*log(n)) where x>=3/2 would for instance be a valid Big O notation for f(n)? The big problem is then to determine the "lower, upper bound"?

Comment: yes it is exact, because O(n) means that there is K>0 that your function is < to K*n so it is also < to K*n*n so it is also O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

"*Big O notation*" being applied on the sum always leaves dominant (the *biggest* ones) terms only. In case of one independent variable one term only will survive. In your case

```
  O(n^2*log(n) + n^(3/2)*log(n)) = O(n^2*log(n))
```

since 1-st term is bigger than the 2-nd:

```
  lim(term1/term2) = lim(n^2*log(n) / (n^(3/2)*log(n))) = lim(n^(1/2)) = inf
```

but it seems, that you made an *arithemic error* in your computations:

```
  (n^2+2n)/n = n + 2, not n^2 + 2 * n
```

in that case

```
  O(n*log(n) + 2*log(n) + n^(3/2)*log(n))
```

the last term which is "n^(3/2)*log(n)" is the biggest one

```
  O(n*log(n) + 2*log(n) + n^(3/2)*log(n)) = O(n^(3/2)*log(n))
```

Comment: Just as the function could be `O(n^99)`, it can be `O(n²*log(n))`, so I'm not convinced a mistake was made, although it's possible. Carefully reading the question, it looks like the time complexities were likely provided by someone else.

Comment: Dmitry, your “always leaves one term only” notion is wrong.  For example, if m and n are independent variables, O(m+n) requires two terms.

Comment: @jwpat7: Thank you for counterexample! I've missed the case of several independent variables.